# How can I query using persistent-mysql using withMySQLConn?

Tags: mysql, database, haskell, yesod, persistent

I'm using [persistent-mysql](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/persistent-mysql-2.1.2.1/docs/Database-Persist-MySQL.html) and trying to find a way to execute a simple command from the `SqlPersistM ()` monad. However I'm running into type errors.

First there is `withMySQLConn defaultConnectInfo`, which has the following type

```
(MonadLogger m, MonadBaseControl IO m, MonadIO m) =>
 (Connection -> m a) -> m a
```

The problem here is that if I try to run this in the `IO` monad, I'll get an error saying there's no `MonadLogger` instance for `IO`.

```
λ> :t withMySQLConn defaultConnectInfo $
        \c -> runSqlPersistM (runMigration migrateAll) c

<interactive>:1:1-13:
    No instance for (MonadLogger IO)
      arising from a use of ‘withMySQLConn’
    In the expression: withMySQLConn defaultConnectInfo
    In the expression:
      withMySQLConn defaultConnectInfo
      $ \ c -> runSqlPersistM (runMigration migrateAll) c
```

It seems there was one in [an older version of `monad-logger`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/monad-logger-0.2.4/docs/Control-Monad-Logger.html), but [not anymore](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/monad-logger-0.3.11.1/docs/Control-Monad-Logger.html). I'm not sure if I'm using this wrong, or if there's an underlying problem. I only have a small cabal project with persistent 2.1.1.4 setup, and trying to run the migrations from `cabal repl`.

If it's of any relevance, here is my whole database setup code

```
{-# LANGUAGE EmptyDataDecls             #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts           #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs                      #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses      #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings          #-}
{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes                #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell            #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies               #-}
module Model where

import Control.Monad.Trans.Control
import Control.Monad.IO.Class
import Control.Monad.Trans.Resource (runResourceT, ResourceT)
import Control.Monad.Logger

import Data.Text (Text)
import Data.Time (UTCTime)
import Database.Persist
import Database.Persist.TH
import Database.Persist.MySQL
import Database.Persist.Sqlite

share [mkPersist sqlSettings, mkMigrate "migrateAll"]
    [persistLowerCase|
     Receipt
         name Text
         createdAt UTCTime
            |]
```

I've tried using `persistent-sqlite` and everything seems to work fine (based on the book tutorial), but I can't seem to get things working in MySQL.

**What I'm looking for is a simple snippet showing how to execute a `SqlPersistM a` query (or equivalent) using `persistent-mysql`.**

*This question is a followup [from a GitHub issue discussion](https://github.com/yesodweb/persistent/issues/355).*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're almost there. You just need to use one of the functions from `monad-logger` to provide a `MonadLogger` context. You may want to try `runStdoutLoggingT`.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I've been looking for. I'll accept the answer as soon as SO lets me.

Comment: @JakubArnold, in the case of a good question with a good answer, it's often best *not* to accept too early. Wait a bit for the question and answer to accumulate more views (help the community) and votes (help yourself and the answerer).